# Focus not shifting after using useRef hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my code where I am getting the ref to the current element I want to focus but the focus isnt going to the element.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log("This is current barcode ref inside", barcodeRef.current);
      barcodeRef.current && barcodeRef.current.focus(); 
    }, 500)
    //barcodeRef.current && barcodeRef.current.focus();
  }, [tableData]);
```

Also this is how I am referencing the input element which I want to focus.

```js
            {tableData.map((row, rowIndex) => (
              <TableRow key={rowIndex}>
                {columns.map(
                  (column) =>
                    !column.hidden && (
                      <TableCell
                        key={column.accessorKey}
                        style={{ width: column.width }}
                      >
                        {column.accessorKey === "ItemName" ? (
                          <Input
                            value={row[column.accessorKey] || ""}
                            onChange={(event) =>
                              handleLeaveItem(
                                rowIndex,
                                column.accessorKey,
                                event.target.value
                              )
                            }
                          />
                        ) : (
                          <Input
                            ref={column.accessorKey === "Barcode" ? barcodeRef : null}//reference to the input of barcode column in table row
                            value={row[column.accessorKey] || ""}
                            onChange={(event) =>
                              handleSaveCell(
                                rowIndex,
                                column.accessorKey,
                                event.target.value
                              )
                            }
                          />
                        )}
                      </TableCell>
                    )
                )}
                <TableCell>
                    <IconButton onClick={() => handleRemoveRow(rowIndex)}>
                      <Delete />
                    </IconButton>
                  </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
```

I have tried using useLayoutEffect as well but didnt work. In the console I am getting this which is the correct Input element I want to focus on.

```js
<div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-colorPrimary css-10tgus4-MuiInputBase-root-MuiInput-root">
::before
<input type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input css-ume8vi-MuiInputBase-input-MuiInput-input" value>
::after
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using MUI TextField or Input?

Comment: use `inputRef` instead of `ref` to get a reference to the actual input element.

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect` needs to depend of the `barcodeRef` like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log("This is current barcode ref inside", barcodeRef.current);
      barcodeRef.current && barcodeRef.current.focus(); 
    }, 500)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [tableData, barcodeRef]);
```

Comment: I tried this also it still isnt working

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your log, input is the child of the current stored element. So reference the input instead of the parent.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log("This is current barcode ref inside", barcodeRef.current);
      barcodeRef.current && barcodeRef.current.firstChild.focus(); //  firstChild
    }, 500)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [tableData, barcodeRef]);
```

Answer (score 0):

your use effect should be depend on the `barcodeRef` also, you need to check `barcodRef` and `barcodeRef.current` before focusing on the element. like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      if(barcodeRef && barcodeRef.current){
        barcodeRef.current.focus(); 
      } 
  }, [barcodeRef]);
```